# Pytorch counting tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to create a Python function that, given inputs `dim` and `m`, generates the tensor of size `[m ** dim, dim]` of the form

```
[[1,...,1,1],
 [1,...,1,2],
 ...
 [1,...,1,m],
 [1,...,2,1],
 [1,...,2,2],
 ...
 [m,...,m,m]]
```

What is the best way of doing this in Pytorch?

Thanks

Comment: please provide input and expected output also describe what have you tried.

Comment: To me this question has the distinct smell of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/344047). What exactly are you generating such a tensor for? My hunch is that you're trying to vectorize an operation containing nested for loops. There's often much more efficient ways of doing this, e.g. by relying built-in pytorch functions and/or by utilizing numpy-style [broadcasting semantics](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: @jodag As you thought, I am trying to vectorise a sum over a ```dim``` dimensional index set of the form ```sum_i_1 sum_i_2 ... sum_i_dim f(x, i_1, i_2, ..., i_dim)``` where the function that you sum over depends upon the indices (it is a ```sin``` function whose arguments depend on the indices). I couldn't think of a good way to do this other than the approach above! Apologies if my comment is difficult to follow, it would be much easier if you could use LaTeX formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this myself using the following code:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

def mat_gen(dim, m): 
    return torch.from_numpy(np.array(np.meshgrid(*[np.arange(1, m + 1, 1) for i in range(dim)])).T.reshape(m ** dim, dim))
```

Here is another function that uses Pytorch only:

```
import torch

def mat_gen(dim, m): 
    return torch.stack(torch.meshgrid(*[torch.arange(1, m + 1, 1) for i in range(dim)])).T.reshape(m ** dim, dim)
```

Answer (score 2):

that's quite an interesting problem there ! Let's first dig a bit in the maths, sample code is below if you want to skip the playing with integers in arbitrary bases.

First, let us notice that you write the index of each row `r` in base `m` (`r = i_{d-1} m**(d-1) + i_{d-2} m**(d-2) + ... + i_0 m**0`, then the `j` element of that row `r` has value `1 + i_{d-j+1}` (`j` being in `[0, d-1]`). This tensor is basically iterating over all integers, written in base `m`.

That being said, the code is easy to come with : simply iterate over all number (or rather their decomposition in base `m`), build a tensor out of this decomposition, concatenate all tensors.

So as to gain a little bit of efficiency, the code below builds the tensor block by block (a block having size m*d) rather than line by line, the last column of a block always being `[1,2,...,m]`.

```
def iter_radix_m(digits, radix):
    """
    utility aux function to iterate over integers decompositions
    digits : list of size(d-1), the d-1 first digits of your number
    radix: 
    """
    index = len(digits)-1
    while digits[index] == radix-1:
        digits[index] = 0
        index -= 1
    digits[index] += 1 

def radix_tensor(m, d):
     # there are m**(d-1) blocks of size m
     nb_blocks = m**(d-1)
     # In there will be stored all blocks until final concatenation
     blocks = []
     digits = [0]*(d-1)
     # Iteration over all blocks
     for i in range(nb_blocks):
         # A column is a tensor of ones, multiplied by the corresponding digit
         # in the m-radix decomposition of i, plus 1
         # The last column is [1,2,...m] always
         cols = [torch.tensor(digits, dtype=int) * torch.ones(m,d-1, dtype=int) + 1] + [torch.arange(1,m+1).view(m,1)]
         #Concatenate these columns to make an (m,d) block
         blocks += [torch.cat(cols, dim=1)]
         iter_radix_m(digits, m)
     # Concatenate all blocks to make an (m**d, d) tensor
     return torch.cat(blocks, dim=0)
```

With m = d = 3:

```
tensor([[1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2],
    [1, 1, 3],
    [1, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 3, 1],
    [1, 3, 2],
    [1, 3, 3],
    [2, 1, 1],
    [2, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 3],
    [2, 2, 1],
    [2, 2, 2],
    [2, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 1],
    [2, 3, 2],
    [2, 3, 3],
    [3, 1, 1],
    [3, 1, 2],
    [3, 1, 3],
    [3, 2, 1],
    [3, 2, 2],
    [3, 2, 3],
    [3, 3, 1],
    [3, 3, 2],
    [3, 3, 3]])
```